# Why is input type "numberDecimal|numberSigned" not working in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to follow a tutorial building a very basic calculator in Android Studio. Like a lot of people here, I keep getting stuck with trying to use a button to add a decimal point into an EditText object.

I've read answers to a number of questions regarding a similar issue.  However, none of them seem to work. The code which I am trying to fix is below.  I'd really appreciate if anyone could take a look and maybe spot something I couldn't.

**Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/newNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    [I have also tried adding this -> android:digits="0123456789.,"]
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="201dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    android:text="1"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="212dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="79dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    android:text="2"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    android:text="."
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText newNumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    newNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newNumber);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button buttonDot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDot);

    // Instantiate listener
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button b = (Button) v;
            newNumber.append(b.getText().toString());
        }
    };

    button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
    button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
    buttonDot.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
}
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: What type of problem do you face?

Comment: I have tried with **12.21**, **.12** and it's working. didn't get your problem

Comment: Thats wierd. Mine refuses to add "." to the EditText. Could this have any connection to the type of SDK/virtual device? Or for that matter any other setting